# Using Scope_Identity() to add 2 foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a question about `Scope_Identity()` and transactions.

I have these three tables and the PK in `MemberDetails` is the FK in the other two tables.

I have been trying to create the stored procedure with `Scope_Identity()` so that the FK are automatically added in the tables, but I can't figure how to do it.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE [MarketingTarget] 
(
    [MTid] int identity (5000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MDOB] date NOT NULL,
    [MSex] char (1) NOT NULL CHECK (MSex IN ('M','F')) DEFAULT 'M',
    [MemberID] int NULL,
    [MTUpdate] Date Null DEFAULT Getdate(),
    PRIMARY KEY ([MTid]),
    FOREIGN KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES [MemberDetails] ([MemberID]) 
            ON DELETE SET NULL 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [MembershipDetails] 
(
    [MDid] int identity (2000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MType] varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (MType IN ('Monthly','Quaterly','Yearly'))  DEFAULT 'Monthly',
    [JoinDate] Date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [ExpiryDate] Date NULL,
    [MsUpdate] Date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [MemberID] int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([MDid]),
    FOREIGN KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES [MemberDetails] ([MemberID]) 
            ON DELETE SET NULL
            ON UPDATE CASCADE  
);

CREATE TABLE [MemberDetails] 
(
    [MemberID] int identity (1000,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MName] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [MSurname] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [MPhone] varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MEmail] varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [MAddress] varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    [MActive] char (1) NOT NULL CHECK (MActive IN ('Y','N')) DEFAULT 'Y',
    [MUpdateDate] Date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [MPhoto] Image NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY ([MemberID])
);
```

```
CREATE PROC spInsertMarketingTarget_test1
    @MDOB date,
    @MSex char (1),
    @MemberID int,
    @MTUpdate Date
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MarketingTarget mt 
            WHERE MemberID = @MemberID) > 0
            RAISERROR ('Fatal error. Member already exist.', 16, 1)

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO MarketingTarget
                SELECT
                    @MDOB, @MSex, @MemberID, @MTUpdate
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    -- Transaction uncommittable
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- Transaction committable
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END CATCH;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertMemberDetails
    @MemberID int = 0,
    @MName varchar(100),
    @MSurname varchar(100),
    @MPhone varchar(20),
    @MEmail varchar(200),
    @MAddress varchar(250),
    @MActive char (1),
    @MUpdateDate Date,
    @MPhoto image
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [MemberDetails] (MName, MSurname, MPhone, MEmail, MAddress, MActive, MUpdateDate, MPhoto)
    VALUES (@MName, @MSurname, @MPhone, @MEmail, @MAddress, @MActive, @MUpdateDate, @MPhoto)

    SET @MemberID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: The if-not-exists-then-insert logic in spInsertMarketingTarget_test1 is creating a race condition for you. You could combine those into a single statement to avoid that issue and then only raiserror when no rows got inserted, i.e.: it already existed.

Comment: Don't catch an error just to select it as a resultset from your proc. Doing so HIDES the error from the caller and will not invoke any error handling the caller has. Just rethrow the error. And why do you need a transaction at all? You have a single DML statement - it either works or fails, no transaction needed. And you shouldn't count just to determine existence - that is often very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have two options:

1. You can write a single stored procedure that takes all the parameters you need to insert the values into your three tables. Then inside that stored procedure, insert into the first table, get the identity value, and then insert into the second and third table, using that identity value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertAllData
    (--list all the parameters needed for all three inserts--)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MemberDetails] (MName, MSurname, MPhone, MEmail, MAddress, MActive, MUpdateDate, MPhoto)
    VALUES (@MName, @MSurname, @MPhone, @MEmail, @MAddress, @MActive, @MUpdateDate, @MPhoto)

    SELECT @MemberID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.MarketingTarget (MemberID, -- other columns --)
    VALUES (@MemberID, -- other values);

    INSERT INTO dbo.MembershipDetails (MemberID, -- other columns --)
    VALUES (@MemberID, -- other values);
END;
```

2. You can have three separate stored procedures, and the first one inserts into the "master" table and returns the newly created identity value back to the calling code. From there, using that value returned, you can then call the second and third stored procedure to insert into the second and third table. Make sure to wrap those three calls into a client-side transaction to ensure proper inserting of the data.